# Fading images loop with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript file that loops between images and fades them.  I am currently using 2 images and when the second image fades, instead of the first image reappearing again, my container is blank for 5 seconds (The current timeout).  However, when the images loop through again, the container is not blank.

Javascript code:

```
function thebackground()
{
    $('div.contain img').css(
    {
        opacity: 0.0
    });
    $('div.contain img:first').css(
    {
        opacity: 1.0
    });
    setInterval('change()', 5000);
}

function change()
{
    var current = ($('div.contain img.show') ? $('div.contain img.show') : $('div.contain img:first'));
    if (current.length == 0) current = $('div.contain img:first');
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.contain img:first') : current.next()) : $('div.contain img:first'));
    next.css(
    {
        opacity: 0.0
    })
        .addClass('show')
        .animate(
        {
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000);
    current.animate(
    {
        opacity: 0.0
    }, 1000)
        .removeClass('show');
};

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    thebackground();
    $('div.contain').fadeIn(1000); // works for all the browsers other than IE
    $('div.contain img').fadeIn(1000); // IE tweak
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue I found was wrapping the change function in the setInterval, and **NOT** having it wrapped as a string.  I also wanted to wrap the entire script within the `.ready()` as well

```
setInterval(function () {change()}, 3000);
```

Here is [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/d6pXy/1/) if you want to experiment.  I hope this answers your question! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This does exactly what I want, greatly appreciative!